# Test always exceed timeout no matter the time I set (NestJS, Jest, TypeORM)

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

My test always throw the error **"Exceeded timeout of (timeout value that I'm using) ms for a hook"**. I already tried to increase the timeout value to 10000, 20000 and even 100000 using jest function "jest.setTimeout()", but it keeps throwing this error.

**Here is a print of the error:**
[image]

**city.e2e-spec.ts**

```
  import * as request from 'supertest';
  import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
  import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
  import { CityModule } from '@app/modules/public/city';
  import { City } from '@app/entity/city/city.entity';
  import { createConnections, getRepository } from 'typeorm';
  import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

  jest.useFakeTimers();
  jest.setTimeout(10000);

  describe('City E2E', () => {
    let app: INestApplication;

    beforeAll(async () => {
      await createConnections();

      const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [CityModule],
        providers: [{ provide: getRepositoryToken(City), useValue: getRepository(City) }]
      }).compile();

      app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
      app.setGlobalPrefix('v1/public');

      await app.init();
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
      await app.close();
    });

    it('[GET] /cities', () => {
      return request(app.getHttpServer())
        .get('/cities')
        .expect(200)
        .expect(['array with cities...']);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably caused by the connection to the database.

`await createConnections();`

Comment: But if I take this line off I get the error "ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found". Is there a correct way to start the connection to the database in E2E tests?

Comment: Probably caused by the connection configuration. In think it is unable to find/connect to the database so it's why you code is blocked at this step

Comment: So, I removed the line with "createConnections()" and ajusted the connection configs. I'm not having the error "Connection default was not found" anymore, but now I'm having the timeout error again. This is being a pain in the ass

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently, and I just found out it was due to a setting in the jest config file.
Can you share your Jest settings?

If you enabled the `fakeTimers` option globally, this messes with the process of setting up the database module (in my case TypeORM). Try adding `doNotFake: ['nextTick', 'setImmediate']` to `fakeTimers`.